# How sessionStorage or localStorage is stored across domains

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js

I want to store data in sessionStorage or localStorage across domains, what should I do? Because the vue project needs to carry the data to the react project, my English is not very good, I hope you can understand what I mean

Comment: You need to store the data on a common server that both domains can access. This problem requires a backend solution

Answer (score 0):

I think this is by design. So I don't think you can do this.

"Data stored in sessionStorage is specific to the protocol of the page. In particular, data stored by a script on a site accessed with HTTP (e.g., http://example.com) is put in a different sessionStorage object from the same site accessed with HTTPS (e.g., https://example.com)."

"localStorage data is specific to the protocol of the document. In particular, for a site loaded over HTTP (e.g., http://example.com), localStorage returns a different object than localStorage for the corresponding site loaded over HTTPS (e.g., https://example.com)."

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: Is there any other way to do something similar? I tried to use window.opne but since it's a GET request, I can't carry a lot of data

Comment: I think it is best to store it on the server if that is possible.